# Are macros/definitions case sensitive in C++?

Tags: c++

Say you had a header file named **Add.h**. Would the program link if you had

```
#ifndef ADD_H
#define Add_H
```

as your include guards?

Edit:
Header file

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef _RATIONAL_H
#define _Rational_H

class Rational
{
    long long _p;
    long long _q;
    void simp();
public:
    Rational();
    Rational( long long P, long long Q = 1);
    Rational( const Rational& );
};
#endif
```

Comment: yeah, everything is case sensitive.

Comment: Do you mean, if you used that as your include guard and included the header from multiple compilation units? Try it and find out.

Comment: Whether the code links depends on the rest of your code...

Comment: isn't this a question you could easily answer yourself by testing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, macros are case sensitive in C++. It's probably a good rule of thumb to assume that everything in most programming languages is case sensitive. In only a few languages would you be able to access, for example, `foo` and `Foo` as the same variable (I'm thinking Visual Basic - not sure how many others there are).

If you're unsure with something as simple as this, the easiest thing to do would be to try it out with your own compiler :)

Edit: To know whether or not it does *actually* work, and the linker isn't just overlooking it because it doesn't necessarily need to be defined (might happen depending on the ifdef logic/circumstances) try the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TEST

bool success = false;

#ifdef Test
bool success = true;
#endif

void main() {
    std::cout << success << std::endl;
    system("pause"); //Wait to press enter before closing
}
```

If the console displays the number 1 (std::cout converts `true` to 1 and `false` to 0, unless you tell it to do otherwise) then the macros are, indeed, case ***in**sensitive*

**Update:** I just tried compiling the above code in Visual Studio 2015, and it does give an output of `0`.

Comment: That is the thing. I tried out something similar to what I am asking and the linker created an executable file that actually worked. Someone told me that it is wrong and that it wouldn't link.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a test you could do to test if it really works. Try that and let us know how it goes?

Comment: I tried running the code and it displayed a 0. So it is case sensitive.  If I have two different conditions like that for the preprocessor directives in a header file what would happen? Because somehow in my case it still linked creating an executable.

Comment: Are you able to post the code for your header file (and any other pertinent headers - source files shouldn't be too relevant) so that we can take a look? It's hard to say using just the two lines above, but as I said it may be due to the ifndef logic that you've implemented.



With the two lines you posted above, all that's happening is that you're checking if a macro is defined and, if so, define another. That doesn't actually impede the compilation process at all, but if there are other parts to the code that you're confused about, then we can hopefully explain those too.

Comment: I posted the code to my header file in my original post. So what it would do is just redefine itself every time it is implemented into another file?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what it does. It's not causing a compile-time error because the pre-processor doesn't care that you've redefined it. The only thing that might cause problems is if you got stuck in an include loop due to the header guard failing :P (which it will - at the moment it's redundant until you match the case of the definition with the conditional).